# Swift iOS Photo Collection using Kingfisher cause memory growth

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, out-of-memory, kingfisher

I have a photo browsing app using UICollectionView and I used Kingfisher to download image from url like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
                    cell.ivPhoto.kf.setImage
```

I debugged using xCode Profile tool and saw that when I scroll through the collection view, memory keep growing because of this object: ImageIO_jpeg_Data, and it linked to Kingfisher. Sometimes when scrolling through a collection view with large images (about 500KB each image), it's very laggy, memory could go up to 500+MB and the app crashed, I saw in lldb it was memory issue. I tried to set this:

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    ImageCache.default.clearMemoryCache()
}
```

but it didn't solve the crash issue.

Comment: I had similiar problems with Kingfisher. I am using https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage for my projects now. This works perfectly.

Comment: are you handling the reuse of your `UICollectionViewCell`'s? I would suspect something to be wrong there, not in KingFisher. Also, KingFisher is writing images to the disk and reading from them there, so it should be not increasing the memory usage of the app.

Comment: Yes I re-use the cell, and I already checked for memory leak in my app. The only things I found is memory growth, and it's caused by Kingfisher. I read on web and they said that Kingfisher is using memory cache, that's the reason @dirtydanee

Comment: can you show how did you override the `prepareForReuse` function in your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass?

Comment: I don't use prepareForReuse funtion, I just use this: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) in my cellForItem function

Comment: @HoangTrung well, that is why you are leaking. You need to clean up the memory for the unused `UIImage` instances. Read this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse

Comment: Set a maximum memory cost, otherwise Kingfisher will use as much ram as there is available. Try with a max of 200 for example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354411/2227743

Comment: @dirtydanee ok let me check that, thanks

Comment: @EricAya I did try that, but still crash, and setting that caused laggy in scrolling thru the collection view

Comment: @cb89 you're right. SDWebImage does solve my issue. Thanks. This is accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but it can help someone else. Kingfisher has unlimited memory cache limit as default. Just set it some value you want.

```
KingfisherManager.shared.cache.maxMemoryCost = 1000000
```

Hope this helps.